# grails throws exception when running grails generate commands

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm running grails 2.4.4 locally. I have the following domain class :

```
class MyClass {

    byte[] posterImage
    String posterType
    String posterName
    static belongsTo = NicheChannel
    static constraints = {
        posterImage(nullable: true, maxSize: 16384000 /* 16000k */)
        posterType(nullable: true)
    }
}
```

When I try running

```
grails generate-controller MyClass
```

or

```
grails generate-views MyClass
```

I get the following exception :

```
| Domain class not found in grails-app/domain, trying hibernate mapped classes...
| Error 2016-01-04 04:30:44,365 [main] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@1cce5986 returned null for URL:jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
  Line | Method
->> 40 | doCall in _GrailsBootstrap$_run_closure2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   64 | doCall in _GrailsBootstrap$_run_closure6
|   45 | doCall in _GrailsGenerate_groovy$_run_closure1
^   40 | doCall in GenerateViews$_run_closure1
| Error 2016-01-04 04:30:44,400 [main] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@269f379b returned null for URL:jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
  Line | Method
->> 40 | doCall in _GrailsBootstrap$_run_closure2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   64 | doCall in _GrailsBootstrap$_run_closure6
|   45 | doCall in _GrailsGenerate_groovy$_run_closure1
^   40 | doCall in GenerateViews$_run_closure1
| Error 2016-01-04 04:30:44,431 [main] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
Message: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@20ed4023 returned null for URL:jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
  Line | Method
->> 40 | doCall in _GrailsBootstrap$_run_closure2
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   64 | doCall in _GrailsBootstrap$_run_closure6
|   45 | doCall in _GrailsGenerate_groovy$_run_closure1
^   40 | doCall in GenerateViews$_run_closure1
| Error Error executing script GenerateViews: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Driver:org.postgresql.Driver@20ed4023 returned null for URL:jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

I even tried

```
grails generate-all MyClass
```

and I get  the same exception.

Comment: `ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.` comes when you face difficulty in connecting to database. Please check if everything is written well in `DataSource.groovy`

Comment: verify that your DB url in`URL:jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Update : This got fixed by appending the packagename to MyClass as follows

```
grails generate-controller <packagename>.MyClass
```